# ValueError: Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` or `(x, y)` while using Fit_generator

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I've been trying to teach a model using a set of training and validation images, and i've been gettin the title error ( i'll post the full one below ).
Alittle lost on how to proceed and the previous questions asked about this topic didn't yield results.
My code snippet is :

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
  preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
  rotation_range=90,
  horizontal_flip=True,
  vertical_flip=True,
)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
      rotation_range=90,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      vertical_flip=True,
    )

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(VAL_DIR,
                                                    target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH),
                                                    batch_size=TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE,
                                                    class_mode=None,
                                                    shuffle=True)
val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_DIR,
                                                target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH),
                                                batch_size=VAL_BATCH_SIZE,
                                                class_mode=None,
                                                shuffle=True)
```

and then i try to teach the model using :

```
history = finetune_model.fit_generator(train_generator,epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, workers=8,
                                   steps_per_epoch=num_train_images // TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE,
                                   validation_data=val_generator,
                                   validation_steps=num_val_images // VAL_BATCH_SIZE,
                                   shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

The error i get is :

```
ValueError: Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, sample_weight)` or `(x, y)`. Found: [[[[-5.30867195e+01 -6.81702271e+01  2.66113968e+01]
   [-5.04675522e+01 -6.62993927e+01  2.90434952e+01]
   [-4.78483849e+01 -6.44285583e+01  3.14755783e+01]
   ...
```

I'd love some direction, as i'm a starting ML student. Would be happy to provide more info.
The images are use are in the jpeg format.
What can i do ? can't seem to find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixing the Bug:**

[Per the documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory), specifying `class_mode=None` gives a generator that **only yields batches of image data, with no targets** (intended for use with `model.predict_generator()`).

`fit_generator` [needs a generator](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator) that yields pairs of `(inputs, targets)`. So you can't fit your model to the generators you're using right now, because those generators don't say what targets the model is supposed to fit. You need to figure out what your labels are, and then choose the appropriate `class_mode` so that those labels get included by the data generators.

**Making Sure The Bug is Fixed:**

Once you've selected the correct `class_mode`, you can sanity-check the data generator by printing/visualizing a batch<sup>1</sup>:

[image: Demonstration of visualizing a batch]

In this example, I'm doing multiclass (bunny, cat, dog) classification, so the default `class_mode=categorical` will work fine.

After getting images and labels for a batch, the first image in that batch is a dog, the first label for that batch is `[0, 0, 1]` (a one in the **2nd** position, counting from zero), and the `class_indices` dict says that dog images have label **2** (counting from zero).

<sup>1. In general, it's a good idea to always carefully check the data here, even if the data generator seems to be working; see [this post](http://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/), under "visualize just before the net".</sup>

Comment: I removed the class_mode and the code started running. But I checked keras ImageGenerator and it has no documentation explaining the class modes, only examples. If my images are labeled only by folder names, what is the correct parameter? Thanks!

Comment: The documentation for the different `class_mode` values (and the inference of class names from folder names) is directly linked in my answer, [first link](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory). If your images are labeled by folder names, and you're doing multiclass classification, the default value of `categorical` is probably what you want. I've added a section to my answer about how to check that the generator is set up correctly, so you can use that to make sure that things are working.

Comment: You are correct, i missed that viewing from my phone. I will try to use the categorical mode and see how my model works. I appriciate the time taken to answer Ollin!